# How to tell my shell script to prompt on SVN conflicts

Tags: bash, shell, svn

I'm writing a semi automated script to deploy changes to the Live web server. But I want my script to prompt when there is a conflict or any other error, so that user can attend to the matter. Just doing `svn up` in my shell script would do it?

Comment: Something is wrong with how you are approaching the deployment. There should not be any conflicts on the deployment servers. They should have been resolved on the development servers themselves. Also, doing an svn up is not the recommended way to deploy applications. I have set up continuous deployment processes for several organizations. Let me know if you want to chat.

Comment: If you still want to stick to you current approach, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020901/how-to-find-out-if-svn-up-finished-successfully).

Comment: Yes true, There were no conflicts so far, but this is just as a precaution.